# Add DataAccess Query Results to View in For Cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, defaultview

I got a function to which I provide an ID, which, in turn, returns a collection of results.
From these, I get yet another set of results, that I display in a datagrid.
With the code below I get the results from the Last Node that has Notes.

```
private void GetNotesList(int Id)
    {
        DataAccess.LexCodeNode LexCodeNode = new DataAccess.LexCodeNode();
        LexCodeNode.Where.LexCodeId.Value = Id;
        LexCodeNode.Query.Load();

        for (int Index = 0; Index <= LexCodeNode.RowCount; Index++, LexCodeNode.MoveNext())
        {
            int LexCodeNodeId = LexCodeNode.LexCodeNodeId;
            DataAccess.LexCodeNote LexCodeNote = new DataAccess.LexCodeNote();
            LexCodeNote.Where.LexCodeNodeId.Value = LexCodeNodeId;

            if (LexCodeNote.Query.Load())
            {
                BindGrid(DgNoteLst, LexCodeNote.DefaultView);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I should do something like

```
Array Notes = new Array();
for (int Index = 0; Index <= LexCodeNode.RowCount; Index++, LexCodeNode.MoveNext())
        {
            int LexCodeNodeId = LexCodeNode.LexCodeNodeId;
            DataAccess.LexCodeNote LexCodeNote = new DataAccess.LexCodeNote();
            LexCodeNote.Where.LexCodeNodeId.Value = LexCodeNodeId;

            if (LexCodeNote.Query.Load())
            {
                Notes.Add(LexCodeNote);
            }
        }
BindGrid(DgNoteLst, Notes); // I should send Notes as a View..
```

My question is: How do I add these values to the **DefaulView** from each cycle.

```
private void BindGrid(DataGrid grid, DataView view)
    {
        grid.DataSource = view;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way..
I made a Stored Procedure to get what I needed and then call it.

```
USE [Table]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Custom_GetNotesList(@LexCodeId int)
AS
BEGIN

Select LexCodeNodeId, Note, Active
From LexCodeNote
Where LexCodeNodeId in ( 
    Select LexCodeNodeId 
    From LexCodeNode
    where LexCodeId = @LexCodeId)

END
```

Here is how I call it.

```
 private void GetNotesList(int Id, int Page)
    {
        DataAccess.LexCodeNode LexCodeNode = new DataAccess.LexCodeNode();
        LexCodeNode.GetNotesList(Id);
        BindGrid(DgNoteLst, LexCodeNode.DefaultView);
    }
```

And the definition in the DataAccess Segment

```
        public bool GetNotesList(int pLexCodeId)
    {
        ListDictionary parameters = new ListDictionary();
        parameters.Add(Parameters.LexCodeId, pLexCodeId);

        return base.LoadFromSql("[" + this.SchemaStoredProcedure + "Custom_GetNotesList]", parameters);
    }
```